# ¿Cómo puedo hacer la suma de una lista hasta llegar a un número en específico?

Tags: python, lista

Estoy calculando el valor del histograma y me da una lista extremadamente larga de la cual quiero sumar el primer 50% del histograma. Ir sumando los datos de la lista y parar cuando se llegue al 'objetivo' y finalmente binarizar la imagen con esos nuevos datos.

```
 import cv2
 imge = cv2.imread('radio.jpg',0)
 img = cv2.resize(imge,(600,300))

 hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
 #print('Calculo del histograma: ',hist)

 b=sum(hist)
 #print('La suma total es de:', b)

 objetivo = b/2
 suma=0

 while suma == objetivo:
     for i in hist:
         suma=suma+i
         print('Valor de i es:', suma)
         #print('Suma a lo largo es:', suma)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega un ejemplo con datos de entrada y salida para mejor entender la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Qué es binarizar?

Comment: Acepta la respuesta que se te dio para poder cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 5):

Si quieres recorrer solo el 50% del histograma puedes extraer una nueva lista con estos datos:

```
hist_mitad = hist[:len(hist) // 2]
```

Con eso tenemos qué equivale a `128` su longitud:

```
print(len(hist_mitad))
```

Por lo que podemos interactuar a partir de esta lista ya que solo te interesa, por lo que comentas, extraer los datos a partir del primer 50% de la lista del histograma.

Luego, podemos recorrer cada uno de los elementos de esta primera mitad y colocar una condición donde si la suma de los elementos del primer histograma es mayor o igual al objetivo, paramos la ejecución del bucle sino, añadimos a suma el valor de cada elemento del histograma:

```
for i in hist_mitad:
    if suma >= objetivo:
        break
    suma += i
```

Según como lo tienes, **el objetivo**:

```
b = sum(hist)
objetivo = b/2
```

**es el siguiente**:

```
[90000.]
```

Aún así, la suma del primer histograma es lo siguiente (en mí caso por la imagen que escogí para el ejemplo) (`print(suma)`):

```
[5955.]
```

**Aún así**, entiendo que quieres hacer un plot de lo que te ha arrojado la mitad del histograma, entonces no deberías hacerlo del total, sino de cada uno de los elementos que te arroja la lista del primer 50% del histograma, en mí caso equivale a:

```
[
[1.09709e+05], [2.96600e+03], [1.77400e+03], [1.18600e+03], [8.19000e+02], 
[5.30000e+02], [3.57000e+02], [2.63000e+02], [1.87000e+02], [1.67000e+02], 
[9.50000e+01], [9.50000e+01], [7.80000e+01], [8.10000e+01], [9.90000e+01], 
[6.80000e+01], [5.20000e+01], [6.60000e+01], [6.10000e+01], [5.70000e+01], 
[6.00000e+01], [4.00000e+01], [4.50000e+01], [3.90000e+01], [4.20000e+01], 
[4.00000e+01], [4.00000e+01], [3.80000e+01], [3.70000e+01], [4.20000e+01], 
[3.20000e+01], [3.60000e+01], [2.30000e+01], [3.00000e+01], [4.00000e+01], 
[3.30000e+01], [3.00000e+01], [3.10000e+01], [2.50000e+01], [1.90000e+01], 
[2.90000e+01], [2.40000e+01], [2.80000e+01], [2.10000e+01], [2.40000e+01], 
[4.60000e+01], [2.70000e+01], [3.20000e+01], [2.70000e+01], [3.40000e+01], 
[2.40000e+01], [3.10000e+01], [2.60000e+01], [2.50000e+01], [2.60000e+01], 
[2.30000e+01], [1.50000e+01], [2.40000e+01], [2.50000e+01], [2.20000e+01], 
[1.60000e+01], [2.50000e+01], [2.80000e+01], [2.90000e+01], [2.10000e+01], 
[2.00000e+01], [2.10000e+01], [1.90000e+01], [2.20000e+01], [3.30000e+01], 
[1.30000e+01], [2.70000e+01], [2.00000e+01], [2.30000e+01], [2.10000e+01], 
[2.60000e+01], [1.30000e+01], [1.90000e+01], [2.20000e+01], [1.70000e+01], 
[1.80000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [2.00000e+01], 
[1.50000e+01], [2.10000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [1.70000e+01], [1.50000e+01], 
[2.60000e+01], [1.70000e+01], [1.30000e+01], [1.60000e+01], [2.00000e+01], 
[2.00000e+01], [1.10000e+01], [1.20000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [1.70000e+01], 
[1.60000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [2.20000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [1.50000e+01], 
[1.80000e+01], [2.00000e+01], [1.60000e+01], [1.50000e+01], [1.70000e+01], 
[2.00000e+01], [1.70000e+01], [1.70000e+01], [2.00000e+01], [2.20000e+01], 
[2.00000e+01], [2.20000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [1.40000e+01], [1.20000e+01], 
[1.40000e+01], [2.00000e+01], [1.60000e+01], [1.80000e+01], [1.80000e+01], 
[1.80000e+01], [1.60000e+01], [2.90000e+01]
]
```

Que sería la mitad de mi histograma total.

Podrías importar `matplitlib`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Hacer un `hist` y mostrar el resultado:

```
plt.hist(hist_mitad)
```

**Código final**:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imge = cv2.imread('radio.jpg',0)
img = cv2.resize(imge,(600,300))
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

hist_mitad = hist[:len(hist) // 2]

plt.hist(hist_mitad)
plt.show()
```

Puedes añadir el número de bloques o `bins` en el método `hist` dependiendo de como lo quieras:

```
# plt.hist(hist_mitad, bins=5)
# plt.hist(hist_mitad, bins="auto")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Adrián, me fue de mucha ayuda tu código.

Comment: Me alegro haber ayudado.